# Mouse moving while unattended

Tags: security

A few minutes ago, to my horror I found my unattended mouse moving and seeming to click on tabs. I promptly rebooted my system and removed Teamviewer (its the only remote connection app that I have installed). After rebooting I ran the command `journalctl -u NetworkManager` and got the following. Is there anything here that suggests an unauthorized access to my laptop (Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS)

```
-- Reboot --
Jun 01 08:41:19 LinuxLaptop systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Jun 01 08:41:19 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533279.8274] NetworkManager (version 1.10.14) is starting... (for the first time)
Jun 01 08:41:19 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533279.8276] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubunt
Jun 01 08:41:19 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533279.8324] manager[0x564d8bab3060]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Jun 01 08:41:19 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533279.8324] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.0283] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.0283] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to "LinuxLaptop"
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.0286] dns-mgr[0x564d8baa71a0]: init: dns=systemd-resolved, rc-manager=symlink, plugin=systemd-resolved
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.0294] rfkill1: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/ieee80211/p
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.0295] manager[0x564d8bab3060]: rfkill: WiFi hardware radio set enabled
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.0295] manager[0x564d8bab3060]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.2843] init!
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.2845]       interface-parser: parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.2845]       interface-parser: finished parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.2845] management mode: unmanaged
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.2849] devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0/net/enp0s25, iface: enp0s25)
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.2849] device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:19.0/net/enp0s25, iface: enp0s25): no ifupdown con
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.2849] devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/net/wlp3s0, iface: wlp3s0)
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.2850] device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:03:00.0/net/wlp3s0, iface: wlp3s0): no i
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.2850] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo)
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.2850] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/lo, iface: lo): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.2850] end _init.
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.2850] settings: loaded plugin ifupdown: (C) 2008 Canonical Ltd.  To report bugs please use the NetworkManage
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.2850] settings: loaded plugin keyfile: (c) 2007 - 2016 Red Hat, Inc.  To report bugs please use the NetworkM
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.2850] (-1951478592) ... get_connections.
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.2851] (-1951478592) ... get_connections (managed=false): return empty list.
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.2969] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.3673] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.4581] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.5495] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.6788] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.8190] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.8859] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.9225] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533280.9708] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.0175] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.0946] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.1394] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.2276] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.2742] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.3084] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.3303] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.3489] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.4000] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.4513] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.4887] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.5358] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.5938] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.6246] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.6445] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.6604] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.6809] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.7107] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.7310] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.7453] keyfile: new connection /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<REDACTED>
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.7620] get unmanaged devices count: 0
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.7621] manager: rfkill: WiFi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.7621] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.7621] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.7622] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'dhclient'
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.7630] Loaded device plugin: NMBondDeviceFactory (internal)
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.7630] Loaded device plugin: NMBridgeDeviceFactory (internal)
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.7631] Loaded device plugin: NMDummyDeviceFactory (internal)
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.7631] Loaded device plugin: NMEthernetDeviceFactory (internal)
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.7631] Loaded device plugin: NMInfinibandDeviceFactory (internal)
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.7631] Loaded device plugin: NMIPTunnelDeviceFactory (internal)
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.7631] Loaded device plugin: NMMacsecDeviceFactory (internal)
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.7631] Loaded device plugin: NMMacvlanDeviceFactory (internal)
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.7631] Loaded device plugin: NMPppDeviceFactory (internal)
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.7632] Loaded device plugin: NMTunDeviceFactory (internal)
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.7632] Loaded device plugin: NMVethDeviceFactory (internal)
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.7632] Loaded device plugin: NMVlanDeviceFactory (internal)
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.7632] Loaded device plugin: NMVxlanDeviceFactory (internal)
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.8047] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-wwan
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.8055] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-wifi
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.8066] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-team
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.8079] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-blu
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.8085] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.8094] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.8099] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.8110] manager: (enp0s25): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.8119] keyfile: add connection in-memory (25697060-7a43-3b1d-889f-23e219a6284d,"Wired connection 1")
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.8127] settings: (enp0s25): created default wired connection 'Wired connection 1'
Jun 01 08:41:21 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533281.8133] device (enp0s25): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external
Jun 01 08:41:22 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533282.0486] wifi-nl80211: (wlp3s0): using nl80211 for WiFi device control
Jun 01 08:41:22 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533282.0488] device (wlp3s0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Jun 01 08:41:22 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533282.0498] manager: (wlp3s0): new 802.11 WiFi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Jun 01 08:41:22 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533282.0507] device (wlp3s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external'
Jun 01 08:41:22 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533282.4701] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Jun 01 08:41:22 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533282.5166] supplicant: wpa_supplicant running
Jun 01 08:41:22 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533282.5167] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: init -> starting
Jun 01 08:41:22 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533282.5806] sup-iface[0x564d8ba87240,wlp3s0]: supports 5 scan SSIDs
Jun 01 08:41:22 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533282.5813] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Jun 01 08:41:22 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533282.5814] device (wlp3s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-s
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.7167] policy: auto-activating connection 'VM7388727'
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.7176] device (wlp3s0): Activation: starting connection 'VM7388727' (736a4742-7599-4703-8a61-6040e3a98f3f)
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.7178] device (wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.7180] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.7184] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.7186] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'VM7388727' has security, but secrets are required.
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.7186] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.7187] sup-iface[0x564d8ba87240,wlp3s0]: wps: type pbc start...
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.7218] device (wlp3s0): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.7222] device (wlp3s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.7224] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'VM7388727' has security, and secrets exist.  No new se
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.7224] Config: added 'ssid' value 'VM7388727'
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.7225] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.7225] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.7225] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.7225] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.7225] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.7355] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: ready -> authenticating
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.8082] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.8380] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> 4-way handshake
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.8601] device (wlp3s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.8602] device (wlp3s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful.  Connected to wireless
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.8603] device (wlp3s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.8612] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.8657] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): dhclient started with pid 3435
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop dhclient[3435]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.40 on wlp3s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x6b01c5d6)
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop dhclient[3435]: DHCPACK of 192.168.0.40 from 192.168.0.1
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.9512] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   address 192.168.0.40
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.9513] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.9513] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   gateway 192.168.0.1
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.9514] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   lease time 864000
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.9514] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   hostname 'LinuxLaptop'
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.9514] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   nameserver '194.168.4.100'
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.9514] dhcp4 (wlp3s0):   nameserver '194.168.8.100'
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.9515] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.9544] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.9559] device (wlp3s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.9563] device (wlp3s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.9564] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop dhclient[3435]: bound to 192.168.0.40 -- renewal in 378539 seconds.
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.9691] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.9692] policy: set 'VM7388727' (wlp3s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jun 01 08:41:25 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533285.9695] device (wlp3s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jun 01 08:41:26 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533286.2410] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jun 01 08:41:28 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533288.0365] manager: startup complete
Jun 01 08:41:28 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533288.9903] manager: (docker0): new Bridge device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
Jun 01 08:41:29 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533289.0020] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/docker0, iface: docker0)
Jun 01 08:41:29 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533289.0020] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/docker0, iface: docker0): no ifupdown configuration found
Jun 01 08:41:29 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533289.2185] device (docker0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-state
Jun 01 08:41:29 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533289.2221] keyfile: add connection in-memory (f49d4a46-b6c4-41d7-9a82-a1740e48768d,"docker0")
Jun 01 08:41:29 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533289.2240] device (docker0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'connection-assumed', sys-iface-st
Jun 01 08:41:29 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533289.2252] device (docker0): Activation: starting connection 'docker0' (f49d4a46-b6c4-41d7-9a82-a1740e48768d)
Jun 01 08:41:29 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533289.2300] device (docker0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 01 08:41:29 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533289.2303] device (docker0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 01 08:41:29 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533289.2306] device (docker0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 01 08:41:29 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533289.2308] device (docker0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 01 08:41:29 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533289.2312] device (docker0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 01 08:41:29 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533289.2314] device (docker0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jun 01 08:41:29 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622533289.2380] device (docker0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jun 01 10:16:50 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622539010.4466] connectivity: (wlp3s0) timed out
Jun 01 10:16:50 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622539010.4468] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jun 01 10:21:20 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622539280.6855] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Jun 01 10:55:36 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622541336.5643] modem-manager: ModemManager no longer available
Jun 01 10:55:36 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <warn>  [1622541336.6398] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open: Authorization check failed: 
Jun 01 10:55:36 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <warn>  [1622541336.6398] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected: Authorization check fai
Jun 01 10:55:36 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <warn>  [1622541336.6399] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open: Authorization check failed: 
Jun 01 10:55:36 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <warn>  [1622541336.6399] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected: Authorization check fai
Jun 01 10:55:36 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <warn>  [1622541336.6411] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.protected: Authorization check fai
Jun 01 10:55:36 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <warn>  [1622541336.6411] error requesting auth for org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.wifi.share.open: Authorization check failed: 
Jun 01 10:55:38 LinuxLaptop systemd[1]: Stopping Network Manager...
Jun 01 10:55:38 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622541338.1649] caught SIGTERM, shutting down normally.
Jun 01 10:55:38 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622541338.1875] device (wlp3s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'unmanaged', sys-iface-state: 'manage
Jun 01 10:55:38 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622541338.1925] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jun 01 10:55:38 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622541338.1926] device (wlp3s0): state change: deactivating -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'managed'
Jun 01 10:55:38 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622541338.2249] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 3435
Jun 01 10:55:38 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622541338.2249] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed bound -> done
Jun 01 10:55:38 LinuxLaptop NetworkManager[1615]: <info>  [1622541338.2552] exiting (success)
Jun 01 10:55:38 LinuxLaptop systemd[1]: Stopped Network Manager.
-- Reboot --
```

Comment: You may want to post this question over at [Information Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com).

Comment: P.S. Whatever you do, if you suspect an intrusion, keep the system offline and detach any non-essential hard drives if you want to perform forensics.

Comment: I don't see anything suspicious in these logs, but I'm not familiar with NetworkManager logs. Why do you think these logs are relevant, though? NetworkManager only decides which networks to connect to. It would typically not be involved at all in an intrusion. TeamViewer logs would be relevant, if you assume the attacker (assuming there has been an attack) hasn't had time to delete the logs.

Comment: *keep the system offline and detach any non-essential hard drives if you want to perform forensics* - not just offline, you must keep it **off**.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Yeah, the correct approach is of course to _not_ perform forensics on the computer that is assumed to be compromised (only OP already started to do that ... still, your advice is the right one)